# Dynamic user controls null, but cannot create them during page_init

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a winforms based website.

This site has a page that contains a repeater.

The repeater contains a number of items, each of which contains a number instances of a user control.

The number of instances varies for each item in the repeater.

Normally, if I was dynamically creating a usercontrol, I would do so in The page_init method so that all its data was then available during postbacks and so on.

However, Until the repeater item has been created, I do not know how many instances of this user control I will need.

So, how do I get round this issue? I need to create these user controls in page_init to have them available, but I do not know how many there will be until it binds.

The only way I can see is to double handle the data, and in page init, create a Dictionary<,List>, and then use this in the DataItem_Bind and DataItem_Create methods. But this seems inefficient.

Is there a more elegant way of managing this issue?

Comment: Have you tried binding your repeater during init ?

Comment: Damn, why did I overcomplicate this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jbl had it.
Having to answer my own question to remove comment on my profile, sorry.